# Why Concatenate not match input shape when it is same?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to concatenate 5 tensors but while concatenating it shows dimension did not match.

I tried with other keras model and its working fine

```
 y_pool
Out[18]: <tf.Tensor 'relu_1_upsample/resize/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(None, 16, 16, 256) dtype=float32>

y_1
Out[19]: <tf.Tensor 'relu_2/Relu:0' shape=(None, 16, 16, 256) dtype=float32>

y_6
Out[20]: <tf.Tensor 'relu_3/Relu:0' shape=(None, 16, 16, 256) dtype=float32>

y_12
Out[21]: <tf.Tensor 'relu_4_1/Relu:0' shape=(None, 16, 16, 256) dtype=float32>

y_18
Out[22]: <tf.Tensor 'relu_5/Relu:0' shape=(None, 16, 16, 256) dtype=float32>

y = concatenate([y_pool, y_1, y_6, y_12, y_18] , axis=-1, name='ASPP_concat')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       y = concatenate([y_pool, y_1, y_6, y_12, y_18] , axis=-1, name='ASPP_concat')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merge.py",
>   line 649, in concatenate
>       return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 431, in **call**
>       self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merge.py",
>   line 362, in build
>       'Got inputs shapes: %s' % (input_shape))
>
> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes
>   except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 16, 16), (None,
>   16, 16, 256), (None, 16, 16, 256), (None, 16, 16, 256), (None, 16, 16,
>   256)]

Comment: As it appears in error message one of the tensors (i.e. the first one) has a shape of `(None, 16, 16)`. Therefore it could not be merged with other tensors over the last axis because they have a shape of `(None, 16, 16, 256)`.

Comment: you can see `y_pool` in first line its shape is `(None,16,16,256)` while concatenate its taking only first three dimension.

Comment: I don't think the error message matches your code, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Indeed, the error message does not match up with your code. However, I assume the `None` axes will also pose an issue, since there is no guarantee that they will all be the same size at runtime and concatentation would fail if they are of different size. Not sure if Tensorflow accepts this.